# Multiple SVN repository logins

Tags: svn

I have an ubuntu system & installed subversion on it. Now i want to create multiple repository on it. All the repository must have their own logins.

for example---example.com/svn/repo1 : user--1

example.com/svn/repo2 : user--2

example.com/svn/repo3 : user--3

Now user1 must not access the repo2 & repo3. & user2 must not access the repo1 & repo3

I am able to create the multiple repos but not the logoins. Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use dav_svn_module

Here is a sample conf, look to [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.ref) to go deeper

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_authz_svn.so

<IfModule dav_svn_module>
<IfModule authz_svn_module>
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /svn

    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn_authz
    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn_passwd
</Location>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

An authz example:

```
cat /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz

[groups]
admin      = foo
graph      = bar
developers = foo,baz

[/]
*           =
@admin      = rw
@developers = rw
@graph      = r

[/branches/prod/*]
*           =
@admin      = rw

[ZCS:/]
*           =
@admin      = rw
@developers = rw
@graph      = rw

[SYMFONY_PLUGINS:/]
*           =
@admin      = rw
@developers = rw

[SYMFONY:/]
*           =
@admin      = rw
@developers = rw
```

Answer (score 0):

Use svnserve instead of Apache server.
Inside the repository you created, you will find a conf directory. Using your preferred text editor edit the following files with these changes:

---

In svnserve.conf
uncomment the following:
    [general]

`anon-access = read` (and change read to none)

```
auth-access = write

passwd-db = passwd
```

---

In passwd file add the usernames and their corresponding passwords in the format username = password

```
[users]
admin = adminspass
dev1 = devspass
```

---

Make similar changes in all your repositories and start the svnserve using the command:
`svnserve -d --foreground -r /root/dir/of/repo`
i.e. if you created the repositories in /home/svn as told in many tutorials, the command will look like `svnserve -d --foreground -r /home/svn`

The repos can be accessed using any svn client with the URL:

```
svn://hostname-or-ip/repo-name
```